# I cannot change the status of contracts in a sandbox environment (Full copy)

Tags: sandbox, contracts

I am having an issue. In a sandbox environment, I cannot change the statut of contracts as system admin, from draft status to any status. This message error displays :" You encountered some errors when trying to save this record Status: Invalid state transition from Draft to In Approval Process for Contract."
To better understand the situation I need to say this : It has been configured on a first sandbox where it works very well and it is once deployed that it malfunctions while the configuration is strictly identical.